# How to delete every other file in a directory from a shell command?

Tags: linux, shell, command-line

I have extracted frames from a video in png format:

```
00000032.png
00000033.png
00000034.png
00000035.png
00000036.png
00000037.png
```

and so on...

I would like to delete every other frame from the dir using a shell command, how to do this?

### EDIT

I think I wasn't clear in my question. I know I can delete each file manually like:

```
rm filename.png
rm filename2.png
```

etc...

I need to do all this in one command dynamically because there are thousands of images in the folder.

Comment: Are the numbers strictly contiguous?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
delete=yes
for file in *.png
do
    if [ $delete = yes ]
    then rm -f $file; delete=no
    else delete=yes
    fi
done
```

This forces strict alternation even if the numbers on the files are not consecutive.  You might choose to speed things up with `xargs` by using:

```
delete=yes
for file in *.png
do
    if [ $delete = yes ]
    then echo $file; delete=no
    else delete=yes
    fi
done |
xargs rm -f
```

Your names look like they're sane (no spaces or other weird characters to deal with), so you don't have to worry about some of the minutiae that a truly general purpose tool would have to deal with.  You might even use:

```
ls *.png |
awk 'NR % 2 == 1 { print }' |
xargs rm -f
```

There are lots of ways to achieve your desired result.

Comment: This is nice because it's not dependent on the numbers being consecutive...though I'm not sure how often someone would want to do this in that case.  Uh...is *.png guaranteed to return the files in alphabetical order?  If not, this won't work.

Comment: @Beska: I edited the answer while you were commenting to note exactly that.  One possible reason for non-consecutive numbers — you've already weeded out half the files already (run this once before).

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler thanks this is a more full proof solution but for now I am going with rm -f *[13579].png since the file names are always consecutive as rendered by the program I am using.

Comment: @Beska: the shell glob operator returns names in sorted order, using the current locale.  So, `*.png` will return the names in a sorted order.

Answer (score 43):

This should do the trick:

```
rm -f *[13579].png
```

which would exterminate every file which name ends with `1` or `3` or `5` or `7` or `9` plus trailing `.png` suffix.

Note: `*` used in pattern matches `0 or more characters` so  `foo1.png` would be removed, but so would `1.png`.

Comment: Please make this the accepted answer this so much shorter and easier to remember then everything else here

Comment: This is the kind of smart quick solution I like from a nerd! :)

Answer (score 5):

```
rm ???????1.png
rm ???????3.png
rm ???????5.png
rm ???????7.png
rm ???????9.png
```

(but make a backup before you try it!).  Replace "rm" with "erase" for dos/windows.

Comment: Okay, I changed it for linux.  The nice thing with the ? wildcard is it should work about the same on DOS.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose every other means files with ending digit 1, 3, 5, 7 or 9, then this solves your problem

```
find . -regex '.*[13579]\.png' -exec rm {} \;
```

Answer (score -1):

Other than what?
You can use * to delete multiple frames. For example rm -f *.png to delete all.

Comment: In English, 'delete every other _object-type_' means delete one, do not delete the next, delete one, do not delete the next, and so on.

Answer (score -1):

This small script remove all png files:

```
$ find . -name "*.png" -exec /bin/rm {} \;
```

Pay attention to the **dot**, it means current directory.

It's the same, but more secure:

```
$ find . -name "*.txt" -delete:
```

Now, remove all files that **does not have** png extension:

```
$ find  . ! -name "*.png" -type f -delete
```

Comment: The problem is not to remove all the files; the problem is to remove half of them.  The 'remove all `*.txt` files' in a directory full of `*.png` files is certainly safer.  You could also use a trailing `+` instead of `\;` to achieve an `xargs`-like effect with `find`.

Comment: Use great caution deleting things with find..just for example this operates not only on the current directory, but recursively on everything under the current directory.